# How to change language of iOS app run time( let say with a button) without changing device language

Tags: ios, swift, localization, multilingual, translate

I have tried everything available on internet but still I am missing something
key values are also same in both .strings files, added Spanish language, Localized my LocalizeAble file
(I don't want to adit schema for simulator)
Any response will be appreciated.Thanks

**My ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {super.viewDidLoad() }

    @IBAction func selectLanguageBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            //sended button tag 1 for selecting English
            firstNameLabel.text = "FirstLabel".localizeableString(loc: "en")
        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            //sended button tag 2 for selecting Spanish
            firstNameLabel.text = "FirstLabel".localizeableString(loc: "es")
        }}} 
  extension String {
    func localizeableString(loc:String) -> String {

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: loc, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}  [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrS0s.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one, It is similar to Brandon answer but more handier.
You have to follow same steps and just write `.localized()` when assigning the string, It will get the string as key

Happy Codding :)

```
let LANGUAGE = "es" // Choose your language

extension String {
        
    func localized() -> String{
        
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: LANGUAGE, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why bother using `NSLocalizedString` when you can retrieve the string directly from the bundle?

Also make sure the file is named `Localizable.strings` in both the `en.lproj` and `es.lproj` and whatever other languages you're supporting.

If the file is named `Test.strings`, then you need to specify the `table: "Test"` parameter for `localizedString`.

```
extension String {
    public static func localized(_ key: String, language: String? = nil) -> String {
        let language = language ?? Locale.preferredLanguages.first?.components(separatedBy: "-").first ?? "en"
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"), let bundle = Bundle(path: path) else {
            return Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
        }
        return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
firstNameLabel.text = .localized("FirstName") //default
firstNameLabel.text = .localized("FirstName", language: "es") //specified
```